# :text in jquery .append

Tags: jquery, html

My question is why does adding :text onto the div result in the text being displayed? It's the functionality I'm after just trying to understand whats happening behind the scenes. I've read through the jquery documentation on .append and the html5 documentation on div attributes.

Answer is probably staring me in the face!

HTML

```
<div id="Content">
<button id="Add">Add Text</button>
</div> 
<div></div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(function () {
  $('#Add').on('click', function () {
    $('<div/>', 
      {text:"why does this work?", x: 2}
     ).appendTo('#Content');
  });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Comment: thanks, that explains it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because of the fact that you're creating a new element and then appending it to the DOM tree.

Behind the scenes, with the `create` call, you're creating a new node as a HTML division (`div`). The, you're giving it some `text`; imagine this as giving it some content. `innerHtml` will also work, but as you say.

Then, you're appending this node to a tree; the DOM engine is re-rendering the block, thereby showing the element.

Since I do not know what's **not** working, I can't compare the two.

Comment: weirdpanda it's working perfectly, I just wasn't sure why. Your answer makes a lot of sense, should have figured it out for myself.

Comment: Haha! Pleasure! Read https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ for a complete list of DOM manipulations! :)

Comment: Weirdpandas reply is very good, just let me add that in native JS you create text nodes as well. This is one of the things simplyfied by jQuery for good.